# disabling query cache in Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, amazon-redshift

I'm having difficulties with disabling query cache in Redshift and I am hoping someone will know how to help me.

I know that to disable query caching I need to "SET enable_result_cache_for_session TO OFF".

after setting this command:

query run-times are still the same just like before setting this parameter.

viewing the SVL_QLOG system table, the "source_query" field is still receiving values. (according to the docs, when the cache is on you can see the source query number that the query result came from, and when the cache is OFF that filed should be NULL).

the queries have no execution description (i think because they use cache and because of that there is not an execution plan. not sure, only assuming).

has anyone encountered this problem and can help me out?

PS. according to the docs, changing the cache parameter is valid for "the session", I still haven't figured out what Redshift considers as a session. rebooting the cluster? closing the query editor? what?

thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of caching in redshift. One is Query caching and the other is result caching. query caching means query execution pattern whereas result caching is actually the saved result of the executed query.
This command **SET enable_result_cache_for_session TO OFF** will turn off the result caching not the query caching.

Redshift query performance should be taken turning off the result caching, not the query caching. When a query get executed for the very first time Redshift saved the query execution pattern which it uses for the subsequent execution of the same query. It also save the result of the query and suplies the result from cache if same query with same parameter get executed.

To get the actual performance of a query you neeed turn off result caching not the query caching. Redshift recomends second time query execution performance.

Redshift internally manage the query caching and outdate the execution pattern by it's own algorithm.

Comment: "To get the actual performance of a query you need turn off result caching not the query caching"  - but I am turning off the result cache as you said